# wp menu displays in the wrong location after adding a new menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have done this million times before and I have no clue what is going on now. I've had one navigation menu, client asked me to add another one and the whole thing collapsed. After I added second navigation, added some pages to it and assigned it to the right location, the first menu appears in the location of the second one, and in the location of the first again it is the first menu.

Here is my register nav code in `functions.php`:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
'primary' => __( 'Top navigacija', 'wpfme' ),
'above' => __( 'Above header', 'wpfme' ),
) );
```

Here is the placement of both in the `header.php` file:

```
<div class="left" id="kkk_top">
            <p><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Above header' )); ?>
</p>
</div><!-- #kkk-top -->
<div id="main_navigation">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Top navigacija' )); ?>
</div><!-- #main_navigation -->
```

I should also add that menu that now appears in the `Above header` location is wrapped in the div with the dynamic id it had when there was no second navigation, and menu that now appears in the `Top navigacija` location is wrapped in a div with a new dynamic id.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the second menu and created it again, placed it in the new theme location and now it s all cool... when in doubt always reboot :)